# Print numbers at index [i][1] from list

Tags: python, list

this is what I have:

```
list = [['Alabama','5235'],['Alaska','3453'],['New York','3643']]

for i in len(list):
    print(list[i][1])
```

So what I want is it to print just the numbers at index [i] [1] in the list. But I get the following error:

```
'int' object no interable
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have:

```
for i in len(list):
```

`len(list)` is a number. You can't iterate through a number.

Try:

```
for i in range(len(list)):
```

Comment: You also have the `enumerate` function, if you want to get the index & the item: `for i, item in enumerate(['a', 'b']):`

Answer (score 3):

Modify your code so that it is like this:

```
for item in list:
    print(item[1])
```

and it will work.

---

The error you are getting at the moment is caused by the fact that you are trying to iterate over a single number, the length of the list- which has no length and therefore will not work. As proof, observe that iterating over `range(len(list))` fixes your code.

Comment: This will work, but not to OP's standards of a multidimensional array.

Comment: @SterlingArcher What do you mean??

Comment: OP wants `item[i][1]`, not `item[1]` (why print out `item[1]` `len(list)` times only to print out the exact same array index?)

Comment: @SterlingArcher This does the exact same as khelwood's answer, just in a neater way.

Comment: Ahhh I see what you mean, completely brainfarted on that one.

Answer (score 0):

The `len()` function returns an integer, which is not iterable. You need to modify the `for` loop to use `range()` as well:

```
list = [['Alabama','5235'],['Alaska','3453'],['New York','3643']]

for i in range(len(list)):
    print(list[i][1])
```

I'd also suggest not calling your list `list`, since it's already used as the name of a [built-in function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
list = [['Alabama','5235'],['Alaska','3453'],['New York','3643']]

for i in range(0,len(list)):
    print(list[i][1])
```

Comment: Note that the `0` parameter of the `range()` function is [not required](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) in this case - though it certainly isn't doing any harm.

Comment: yes, i know but i think is quicker to understand :)